# I want to play RTMP URL in VLCPlayer, but it's not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, vlc

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  VLCVideoView  *videoView = [[VLCVideoView alloc] initWithFrame:[[window contentView] bounds]];
    [[window contentView] addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView setAutoresizingMask: NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable];

    // Init the player object
  VLCMediaPlayer *player = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithVideoView:videoView];

    [player setMedia:[VLCMedia mediaWithPath:@"rtmp://192.168.100.15:1935/vod"]];
    [player play];
}
```

I want to play **RTMP** URL in VLCPlayer, but it's not working. I have tried many SDK's but have not got the solution yet.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: I am not able to play the video in  VLCMediaPlayer

Comment: you URL is not working on VLC desktop application either. Verify your url works then try to implement in iOS.

Comment: you can test URL in VLC desktop application by going into File --> Open Network and then add URL in field under network tab and click open.